# How do I initialize and fill a vector of type vector<vector<int> >?

Tags: c++

I am trying to return a write a function that creates a `vector<vector<int> >` and fills it and returns it. I am facing segmentation fault when trying to push elements into a `vector<vector int>`. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
 vector<vector<int> > Solution::prettyPrint(int A) 
    {
        vector<vector<int>> arr;

        for(int x=1;x<(2*A);x++)
        {
            for(int y=1;y<(2*A);y++)
            {
                int xp=x,yp=y;
                if(x>A) xp=2*A-x;
                if(y>A) yp=2*A-y;

                int min=(xp<yp)?xp:yp;

                arr[x-1].push_back(A+1-min);
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: before you `push_back` into `arr[x-1]` you have to initialize the vector at this position

Comment: Do you need the individual vectors to be of varying length? Otherwise, maybe using some suitable C++ 2D vector template class is better. If the matrix is dense, consider boost::matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do (assuming your matrix is of size `ROWS x COLS`)

```
vector<vector<int>> arr(ROWS, vector<int>(COLS));
```

and there is no more need for `push_back` anymore. The whole memory for the 2D array is now reserved so you can just use `arr[i][j]` to write into it. The code is also a bit faster than using `push_back`, since `push_back` does slow re-allocations when it needs to resize the vector.

However try avoiding such nested vectors as they are slow. Use a flat vector instead and map from 2D to 1D and vice versa.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr[x-1].push_back(A+1-min);
```

You are trying to access `arr[x-1]`, but `arr` is an empty vector at that moment.

Since you know that `arr` is going to be of size `2*A-1` (at least that is what comes out from your code), you can put a

`arr.resize(2*A-1);` before the beginning of the outer loop, or directly when declaring it:

`vector<vector<int> > arr(2*A-1);`

You can go further and initialize even the inner vectors:

```
    for(int x=1;x<(2*A);x++)
    {
        arr[x-1].resize(2*A-1);
        for(int y=1;y<(2*A);y++)
```

and substitute

`arr[x-1].push_back(A+1-min);`

with

`arr[x-1][y-1]=(A+1-min);`

Answer (score 0):

That's right don't go in complex structures save your time and energy and make your project faster. Take a 2D array instead of `push_back` use `arr[i][j]`